# Django ORM how to Round an Avg result

Tags: django, orm, model, rounding, average

I have a model in which I use Django ORM to extract Avg of values from the table. I want to Round that Avg value, how do I do this?

See below I am extracting Avg price from Prices model grouped by date in format YYYY-MM, I want to automatically extract the average values rounded to the closest number.

```
rs = Prices.objects.all.extra(select={
    'for_date': 'CONCAT(CONCAT(extract( YEAR from for_date ), "-"),
        LPAD(extract(MONTH from for_date), 2, "00"))'
    }).values('for_date').annotate(price=Avg('price')).order_by('-for_date')
```

Comment: Have you worked this out by chance?

Comment: Update: a similar function to the given answers was added in `Django v2.2` under the name [`Round`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.Round)

Answer (score 48):

Use [Func() expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions).

Here's an example using the Book model from [Django Aggregation topic guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/aggregation/) to round to two decimal places in SQLite:

```
class Round(Func):
    function = 'ROUND'
    template='%(function)s(%(expressions)s, 2)'

Book.objects.all().aggregate(Round(Avg('price')))
```

This allows the round function to be parameterised (from @RichardZschech's answer):

```
class Round(Func):
  function = 'ROUND'
  arity = 2

Book.objects.all().aggregate(Round(Avg('price'), 2))
```

Comment: Depending on the complexity of your annotation or aggregation, you may need to assign an alias. 

e.g. 
`Book.objects.all().aggregate(rounded_avg_price=Round(Avg('price')))`

Comment: @Blairg23, thanks for the edits! But don't you think that the bold and large headers make the text a bit too loud? In my experience using bold and large headers is rare in StackOverflow and they are mostly used to structure longer answers.

Comment: @mrts I was just preparing it to be a longer answer! ;) But also, I never think being more explicit is a bad thing :)

Comment: @Blairg23, right - but does the current version look good to you?

Comment: @mrts It looks fine, but I always prefer to make the statements stand out more from the code examples, so I boldify or headerify any text that I consider the "opening line" for a bit of code examples. Personal preference, I guess.

Comment: @mrts Also, shouldn't you keep the changes I made in terms of the latest 1.11 docs and the 2.1 docs as well?

Comment: @Blairg23, thanks, all good then! Regarding 1.11 docs - I think it is more succinct to have links only to 2.1 docs. The relevant part of the API is the same and we can assume that people are intelligent enough to switch to 1.11 if they need to.

Comment: I got: "TypeError: Complex aggregates require an alias" with this solution and can not find any way around it :(

Answer (score 22):

Building on previous answers, I've come to this solution to make it work for **PostgreSQL**:

```
from django.db.models import Func

class Round2(Func):
    function = "ROUND"
    template = "%(function)s(%(expressions)s::numeric, 2)"

# Then use it as ,e.g.:
# queryset.annotate(ag_roi=Round2("roi"))

# qs.aggregate(ag_sold_pct=Round2(Sum("sold_uts") / (1.0 * Sum("total_uts"))) * 100
```

Answer (score 16):

Improving on @mrts answer.

This allows the round function to be parameterised:

```
class Round(Func):
  function = 'ROUND'
  arity = 2

Book.objects.all().aggregate(Round(Avg('price'), 2))
```

Comment: This doesn't work in PostgreSQL. Any way to use arity with psql?

Comment: I updated your answer, but I also added it to the answer with more votes and will flag that answer to be the accepted answer.

Comment: I'm getting this
```django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: function round(double precision, integer) does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.```
msonsona's solution worked for me but can't use arity with that.

Comment: @rain01 can you try rounding to `2.0` rather than `2`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13113096/how-to-round-an-average-to-2-decimal-places-in-postgresql

Answer (score 6):

Django has the `Round` function. For more detail please see [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#round)

Comment: This function is available since Django >= 2.2. In the developer Version from 3.3 they add the precision argument.

Answer (score 5):

I needed to have both **PostgreSQL** and **SQLite** support, but also keep the ability to specify the number of digit to keep.

Build on previous answers :

```
class Round(Func):
    function = 'ROUND'
    arity = 2
    # Only works as the arity is 2
    arg_joiner = '::numeric, '

    def as_sqlite(self, compiler, connection, **extra_context):
        return super().as_sqlite(compiler, connection, arg_joiner=", ", **extra_context)

# Then one can use it as:
# queryset.annotate(avg_val=Round(AVG("val"), 6))
```

I would have prefered something cleaner like

```
if SQLITE:
    arg_joiner=", "
elif PGSQL:
    arg_joiner = '::numeric, '
else raise NotImplemented()
```

but did not find how, feel free to improve !

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice answer.