# How to get the float result with certain precision in the F() expressions of Django queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

```html
addon_income = round(pendingAmount*0.1, 2)
print(addon_income)  # if pendingAmount = 6, addon_income = 0.6 which is ok here

Wallet.objects.filter(id=###).update(
    active=F('active')+addon_income, total=F('total')+addon_income,
    uddate_time=timezone.now()
)
```

In the queryset above, if the F('active') = 41.2, F('total') = 41.2, and addon_income = 0.6, the active and total becomes 41.800000000000004 and 41.800000000000004 after the updating.

I tried to use round() in the queryset as shown below:

```html
Wallet.objects.filter(id=###).update(
    active=round(F('active')+addon_income, 2), total=round(F('total')+addon_income, 2),
    uddate_time=timezone.now()
)
```

but it returns error: type CombinedExpression doesn't define **round** method

Anyone has any suggestion? Thx!

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solution in this post: [Django ORM how to Round an Avg result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793759/django-orm-how-to-round-an-avg-result)

```html
class Round(Func):
  function = 'ROUND'
  arity = 2

Book.objects.all().aggregate(Round(Avg('price'), 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Django has a `Cast` function that use can use in queries. In that function, you can specify `FloatField(decimal_places=2)`

Comment: Django model `FloatField` has no argument named `decimal_points`

Comment: @JPG: yep, meant `places`

Comment: `FloatField` has neither `decimal_places` nor `places` parameter. The Django documentation doesn't have anything like that for that field, in any of the available versions: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FloatField