# Django Performance | Recalculating a field value in all related models after updating a model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I want to learn what is the best approach to recalculate a model field value(`total_cost` in my `Product` model class) in all related models after updating a model. I wrote a piece of code and it works but it takes long time. How can I speed up my code? Here is model classes

```py
#models.py
class Product(..):
    total_cost = models.FloatField(...)
    materials = models.ManyToManyField(Material, through="MaterialProduct")


    def calculate_cost(self):
        return round(calc_material_price(self.materialproduct_set.all()),2)

    def calc_material_price(self, mylist):
        res = 0
        for m in mylist:
            res += m.material.price * m.material_rate
        return res

class Material(..):
    price = models.FloatField(...)

class MaterialProduct(..):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, ..)
    material = models.ForeignKey(Material, ..)
    material_rate = models.FloatField()
```

- And my serializer sample

```py
class UpdateProductMaterialSerializer(..):
    #...
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        #in front-end total cost calculated and I assign it here directly
        instance.total_cost = self.initial_data.get("total_cost")
        instance.save()
        mylist_data = self.initial_data.get("mylist")
        material_list_for_update = []
        for item in mylist_data:
            material = item.get("material")
            material_instance = Material.objects.get(pk=material["id"])
            # I use this list for updating all Products
            material_list_for_update.append(material_instance)

            material_rate = item.get("material_rate")
            mp = MaterialProduct.objects.filter(product=instance, material=material_instance).first()
            mp.material_rate = material_rate
            mp.save()# here my one product is updated successfully


            # TO UPDATE ALL PRODUCTS I call below method
            # But this takes 15 seconds
            update_all_product_by_sent_materials(material_list_for_update)
        return instance

    def update_all_product_by_sent_materials(self, material_list):
        for material in material_list:
            for mp in MaterialProduct.objects.filter(material=material):
                mp.material.total_cost = mp.material.calculate_cost()
                mp.material.save()
```

- **Maybe I should use `total_cost` as property in my Product model class and use it. But I dont know how to approach this problem.**
- Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Maybe I should use total_cost as property in my Product model class and use it.

I think its a good idea, and not to store this value in DB as well. But it will not reduce time to calculate the cost. Maybe you can use [**`aggregation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet) to reduce the time like this:

```
from django.db.models import Sum, F
....

@property
def calculate_cost(self):
    cost = self.materialproduct_set.aggregate(cost=Sum(F('material__price') * F('material_rate')))['cost']
    return round(cost, 2)
```

Basically it will aggregate the value from DB so you don't have to make a loop and calculate manually. Also, it will reduce DB hits so performance should improve.

---

Improved answer based on this [**`SO Answer`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793759/django-orm-how-to-round-an-avg-result):

```
from django.db.models import F, Func, Sum

class Round(Func):
    function = 'ROUND'
    template='%(function)s(%(expressions)s, 2)'

# rest of the code

@property
def calculate_cost(self):
    cost = self.materialproduct_set.aggregate(cost=Round(Sum(F('material__price') * F('material_rate'))))['cost']
    return cost
```